# How to Filter individual columns within a Cognos Report

Tags: cognos

All data are coming from one table. Date is based on the creation_date field of the table. I would like to create a report similar to the example below:

```
                No. Prior to             No. On
                 10/01/2015               10/1/2015           Total No.      
 a                     5                    1                   6
 b                     10                   3                   13
 c                     1                    0                   1
```

I could not figure out how to display the combine results on the same "Report Page". I have to create 2 report pages one is for the prior date and the other is for the date "on".

Comment: You should note which version of Cognos, and which report writer you're using.  If possible, post what you've tried and what you can't get working.  We can't see what your table looks like, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. If I understand your data correctly do this.

In your report create query with query items:

1. Type (a,b,c etc)
2. [No. Prior to 10/01/2015] with Aggregate Function = 'Total' and with expression

   ```
   case when creation_date < to_date('10/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        then 1 else 0 end
   ```
3. [No. On 10/1/2015] with Aggregate Function = 'Total' and expression

   ```
   case when creation_date >= to_date('10/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        then 1 else 0 end
   ```
4. [Total No.] with expression

   ```
   [No. Prior to 10/01/2015] + [No. On 10/1/2015]
   ```

And create simple table with this values.

Or you can try to do it with crosstab.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I will try this out. Thanks.